# convert unicode string into array. Django-Python

Tags: python, django, unicode, unicode-string

I receive via POST an unicode string like this:

```
u'[<Word: colors>, <Word: red>, <Word: blue>, <Word: yellow>, <Word: green>, <Word: orange>, <Word: purple>, <Word: brown>, <Word: white>, <Word: black>, <Word: grey>]'
```

I want it to be an array or a dictionary so I can work with it.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: String? `"[<Word: colors>, <Word: red>, <Word: blue>, <Word: yellow>, <Word: green>, <Word: orange>, <Word: purple>, <Word: brown>, <Word: white>, <Word: black>, <Word: grey>]
"`

Comment: Yes, it was originally a list of objects, but, after going through HTML it comes back like that, but being an unicode string

Comment: I think you should look at it from the other end, and make it so that the string you receive in POST is something easier to work with.

Comment: Well, now that you say it you are right. Don't know why didn't I think of it

Answer (score 2):

You should use a module for parsing a structured text, for example, [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Basically the grammar should look like this:

```
import pyparsing as pp

s = u'[<Word: colors>, <Word: red>, <Word: blue>, <Word: yellow>, <Word: green>, <Word: orange>, <Word: purple>, <Word: brown>, <Word: white>, <Word: black>, <Word: grey>]'

term = pp.Literal('<') + pp.Literal('Word') + pp.Literal(':') + pp.Word(pp.alphas) + pp.Literal('>')
expr = pp.Literal('[') + term + pp.ZeroOrMore( pp.Literal(',') + term ) + pp.Literal(']')

r = expr.parseString(s)
```

and then retrieve parse results from `r`. Check examples on the project site. Probably you'll need to set up specific parser callbacks on the items you wish to extract using setParseAction():

```
import pyparsing as pp

s = u'[<Word: colors>, <Word: red>, <Word: blue>, <Word: yellow>, <Word: green>, <Word: orange>, <Word: purple>, <Word: brown>, <Word: white>, <Word: black>, <Word: grey>]'

colors = []

term = pp.Literal('<') + pp.Literal('Word') + pp.Literal(':') + pp.Word(pp.alphas).setParseAction(lambda s: colors.append(s[0])) + pp.Literal('>')
expr = pp.Literal('[') + term + pp.ZeroOrMore( pp.Literal(',') + term ) + pp.Literal(']')

r = expr.parseString(s)
```

now `colors` contains the list of colors and so on...

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a way to change the format of your data (because as I see you try to output list of python objects to form field what is not good idea).

Without more information about your code I can offer this:

output to form field `'colors,red,blue,yellow...'`

then after post: `list_of_values = input.split(',')` (where input is recieved string from post)

Also you can use this code based what output you need

```
print map(lambda val: val.strip(' <>'), s.strip('[]').split(','))
print map(lambda val: val.strip(' <>').split(':')[1].strip(), s.strip('[]').split(','))
```

Also you can serialize or pickle data.

Comment: This approach will break if elements contain "bad characters" like , < > etc

Comment: @user3159253, yep! This is only a variant of solution and of course it does not covers all possible variants of data. The best way IMHO is to   change format of post data.

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above, structured text (especially with such a simple grammar) should be parsed as, well, a structured text, not just a sequence of symbols. Explicitly written grammar would save you from hours of debugging if things eventually change. Any of "let's split it by delimiters" or "let's use a simple RE" approach doesn't survive a long run.

Comment: @user3159253, I agree with you but also I think that you should build your programm as simple as possible. And use less dependences as possible. So I offer variant with serialization which use builtin tools of language if you realy want to send structure to form, but I think that there must be way to avoid this.